# apache mutile host reverse proxy rewrite

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, proxy

I would like to have apache acting as reverse proxy and redirect URLs to different Host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteEngine       On
RewriteRule         ^/app1/(.*) http://192.168.56.102:10001/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse    /app1/ http://192.168.56.102:10001/

RewriteRule         ^/(.*) http://192.168.56.102:82/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse    / http://192.168.56.102:82
ServerName servername.local
</VirtualHost>
```

The code above work well and redirect my URL :

- servername.local to port 82
- servername.local/app1/ to the port 10001

I would like to have also the servername.local/app1 to redirect to port 10001 but this doesn't work I have to add the   **/**  add the end of the URL   I tried to add

```
 ProxyPassReverse    /app1 http://192.168.56.102:10001/
```

But it doesn't work is there a way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrap your rewrites and just use ProxyPass. You're confusing what ProxyPassReverse does with what ProxyPass or RewriteRule with the P flag does.

Also, you're not "redirecting" you're proxying. If you want to proxy /app1 then don't include the trailing slash when you setup your rewriterule or proxypass for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer if i use 
ProxyPass /app1 http://192.168.56.102:10001/
ProxyPass / http://192.168.56.102:82/ 

It worked but I use RewriteRule and ProxyPass because I have a problem that I cannot solve when I redirect to the app1 if i use /static.css in a index.html file the ressource will  be loaded with the base url instead of http://192.168.56.102:82/app1/static.css but http://192.168.56.102:82/static.css

If I use static.css in the index.html of the app1 it work but I use a code that is not mine and all the static resources are prefixed with the slash

Comment: sorry http://192.168.56.102/static.css instead of http://192.168.56.102/app/static.css